# Storing Edge Data in Adjacency List?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, graph

I'm trying to create a simple directed graph data structure backed by a `Hashtable` which looks like this:

```
private Hashtable<V, List<Edge<V, K>>> adjacencyTable;
```

Where `V` is the vertex type and `K` is the data stored in an edge. The `Edge` class simply stores a reference to the two vertices it lies between as well as some object of type `K`. So...

```
1 | (1, 2, data_1), (1, 3, data_2)
2 | (2, 3, data_3)
3 | (3, 1, data_4)
```

So in order to do something simple like `removeVertex(3)`, I have to loop through all the edges for each vertex, check if their `to` property is equal to the vertex I'm trying to remove, and then delete them. Is there a better way to implement something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you're right this is an awkward choice. Consider instead using

```
Map<V, Map<V, K>> adjacencies = new Hashmap<>();
```

The nodes adjacent to `p` are `adjacencies.get(p).keyset()`, and the data for edge `p->q` is  `adjacencies.get(p).get(q)`.

Removing vertex `r` is bound to be a tricky operation because you need to remove the both in- and out-edges of `r`.  However you can make it quick by maintaining a parallel "reverse adjacency" list.

```
Map<V, Set<V>> reverseAdjacencies = new Hashmap<>();
```

Every time you add an adjacency `p->q` with something like:

```
Map<V, K> edgesFromP = adjacencies.get();
if (edgesFromP == null) {
  edgesFromP = new HashMap<>();
  adjacencies.put(p, edgesFromP);
}
edgesFromP.put(q, nodeData);
```

the reverse map needs to be updated, too, with something like

```
Set<V> edgesToQ = reverseAdjacencies.get(q);
if (edgesToQ == null) {
  edgesToQ = new HashSet<>();
  reverseAdjacencies.put(q, edgesToQ);
}
edgesToQ.add(p);
```

Now to delete node `r`,

```
// Remove the in-edges to r.
for (V p : reverseAdjacencies.remove(r)) {
  adjacencies.get(p).remove(r);
}
// Remove r and all its out-edges
adjacencies.remove(r);
```

I've left out details like null checks.

Comment: Thanks. Can this model be extended to a directed multigraph?

Comment: Also, wouldn't this method be slightly slower since each graph operation needs to update two collections?

Comment: @Carpetfizz It's a tiny bit slower and takes a constant factor more space to maintain the reverse map. It's enormously faster to implement delete vertex because  you don't need to search all the adjacencies to find the in-edges. I.e. delete is O(1) rather than O(n).  If you have a graph with a few million edges, this is a big difference.  You asked about delete. Many, many data structures trade constant factors of run time and/or space for asymptotic speed.

Comment: @Carpetfizz Sure you can make a multigraph by using suitable edge data `K`. E.g. a list, where the list length is the edge arity and the contents are the edge labels.